# Golang: running `go build` on save using vim (macvim) and vim-go

Tags: vim, go, macvim

I am recently moving from sublime 3 go to mvim (vim on the mac os) and am trying to get my Golang development environment to be as similar on vim to my sublime implementation as possible.

Within my sublime setup, it runs `go build` anytime I save the a Go file. This provides me instant feedback on if I have unused vars or other info `go build` provides.

I'm attempting to move to vim, and am wondering if I can have this functionality implemented there as well. I am using vim-go but have not found a setting to implement this.

In short I want to run `:GoBuild` upon the saving of a Go file while using vim / vim-go. Is this Possible and how do I do so?

Comment: Yes, but Im looking to have GoBuild run automatically upon the saving of a go file. - Will edit question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

yes, use vim `autocommand` to run `:GoBuild`:

> You can specify commands to be executed automatically when reading or
>   writing a file, when entering or leaving a buffer or window, and when
>   exiting Vim.  The usual place to put autocommands is in your .vimrc or
>   .exrc file.

Run the following command:

`:autocmd BufWritePre *.go :GoBuild`

Now each time you save your Go file with `:w` it will run `:GoBuild` too.
The event type is `BufWritePre`, which means the event will be checked just before you write `*.go` file.

> `BufWritePre` starting to write the whole buffer to a file
>   `BufWritePost` after writing the whole buffer to a file

and:

> When your .vimrc file is sourced twice, the autocommands will appear
>   twice. To avoid this, put this command in your .vimrc file, before
>   defining autocommands:
>
> ```
> :autocmd! " Remove ALL autocommands for the current group.
> ```
>
> If you don't want to remove all autocommands, you can instead use a
>   variable to ensure that Vim includes the autocommands only once:
>
> ```
> :if !exists("autocommands_loaded")    
> :  let autocommands_loaded = 1    
> : au ...  
> :endif
> ```

like this (put this at the end of your vim startup file):

```
:if !exists("autocommands_loaded")
:  let autocommands_loaded = 1
:  autocmd BufWritePost *.go :GoBuild
:endif
```

ref:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html

Answer (score 0):

Create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/go.vim` with:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.go :GoBuild
```